# Net Core: Automapper for Mapping Id to ClassName+Id in Generic Repository

Tags: c#, class, .net-core, automapper

We have a Database, Domain layer, and generic repository (not my choice) from company architect.

Trying to map from Employee Database Scaffold class to Employee Domain Class.
This is code to map, if all class member names are exactly the same.

```
Mapper.CreateMap<EmployeeData, EmployeeDomain>();
```

However, primary key members in database class are named Id (to fit with generic repository). So how would I create an inherited or new AutoMapper function of class, and map Id to EmployeeId in Domain, while mapping other members ?

Here's how to manually map Id to Employee Id. I need to create a function accepting any class (ProductId, SalesId, CustomerId, etc), and map id to "ClassName" + id, while mapping other same name members correctly .

```
Mapper.CreateMap<EmployeeData, EmployeeDomain>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.EmployeeId, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Id))
```

Function should ideally be able to accept other Automapper functions like .ReverseMap, etc

Comment: Try something like this. 
`Mapper.CreateMap<Employee, EmployeeDomain>().ForMember(dest => dest.EmployeeId, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => string.Format("{0}{1}", src.EmployeeId, src.Id)))`

Comment: hi @RahulNikate just updated question to explain issue

Comment: That's pretty clear explanation now. Give me some time, I'm working on it.

Comment: You need `ForAllMaps` and the string based `MapFrom`. People did this before.

Comment: _Trying to map from Employee Database Scaffold class to Employee Domain Class_ so you have _explicit_ data models? Hopefully that database is not the main data store in which your entities live. If thats the case, IMO you should be thinking about replacing your data models with _mapping models_, in other words, implementations of `IEntityTypeConfiguration<T>` for every domain model.

Comment: Might be interested in https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Configuration.html#naming-conventions

Comment: ok, I will research the documentation, if someone has explicit with code sample, feel free to place in answer, and I can send points, thanks